# Excessive logs from ViewDragHelper from Android drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am disableing the Android navigation drawer when my user performs certain actions involving dragging objects. This is to keep them from accidentally opening the drawer. The problem is I am getting flooded with log messages. This is making it difficult to trouble shoot other issues.

This is how I lock the drawer.

```
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

This is the log messages I am getting.

```
E/ViewDragHelper: Ignoring pointerId=0 because ACTION_DOWN was not received for this pointer before ACTION_MOVE. It likely happened because  ViewDragHelper did not receive all the events in the event stream.
E/ViewDragHelper: Ignoring pointerId=0 because ACTION_DOWN was not received for this pointer before ACTION_MOVE. It likely happened because  ViewDragHelper did not receive all the events in the event stream.
E/ViewDragHelper: Ignoring pointerId=0 because ACTION_DOWN was not received for this pointer before ACTION_MOVE. It likely happened because  ViewDragHelper did not receive all the events in the event stream.
E/ViewDragHelper: Ignoring pointerId=0 because ACTION_DOWN was not received for this pointer before ACTION_MOVE. It likely happened because  ViewDragHelper did not receive all the events in the event stream.
E/ViewDragHelper: Ignoring pointerId=0 because ACTION_DOWN was not received for this pointer before ACTION_MOVE. It likely happened because  ViewDragHelper did not receive all the events in the event stream.
E/ViewDragHelper: Ignoring pointerId=0 because ACTION_DOWN was not received for this pointer before ACTION_MOVE. It likely happened because  ViewDragHelper did not receive all the events in the event stream.
E/ViewDragHelper: Ignoring pointerId=0 because ACTION_DOWN was not received for this pointer before ACTION_MOVE. It likely happened because  ViewDragHelper did not receive all the events in the event stream.
```

Comment: Have you had any success in mitigating this?

I'm having a similar issue in that I needed to explicitly reorder views along the Z axis when opening the navigation drawer. This works just fine when the drawer is controlled via a button in the action bar, but results in that same log message being called (along with some inconsistent open/close behaviour) when reordering is done within onDrawerSlide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it using **requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent** function like this:

```
public void blockMainMenu(){
    ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
}
public void unblockMainMenu(){
    ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
}
```

So, when I block my DrawerLayout, I disallow touch events, and Log not shows a lot of error messages saying that they are a lot of events lost.

Hope this can help you!